# Dynamic handling of ng-hide attribute in Angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular.js. I am testing dynamic population of ng-hide attribute. Selecting false should make the text visible. But it's not working.         Please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>Select an Option</p>
<select ng-model="selectedVal" ng-options="x for x in option" >

</select>
<p  ng-hide= "{{selectedVal}}" >I am  visible.</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.option = ["True", "False"];
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `ng-hide= "selectedVal"`, not `ng-hide= "{{selectedVal}}"`, you don't need to interpolate it with `{{}}`. Also change your array of strings `["True", "False"]` to boolean `[true,false]`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<p>Select an Option</p>
<select ng-model="selectedVal" ng-options="x for x in option" >

</select>
<p  ng-hide= "selectedVal" >I am  visible.</p>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.option = [true, false];
});
</script> 

</body>
</html>
```